# (Visual Studio) Django error when running on local host.. used a template?

Tags: python, django

I'm simply using the Python Tools "Django Web Project" template and each time I try to run the site on my local host i receive this error.

```
ValueError at /

dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 11; 2 is required

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:54034/
Django Version:     1.7
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    


Server time:    Sat, 6 Sep 2014 00:04:46 -0400
```

Answer (score 1):

In Your views try removing RequestContext

```
return render(request, 'app/index.html',

    {
        'title':'Home Page',
        'year':datetime.now().year,
    }
)
```

instead of

```
return render(
    request,
    'app/index.html',

    RequestContext(request,
    {
        'title':'Home Page',
        'year':datetime.now().year,
    })
)
```

looks like a PTVS bug
refer to
http://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/2653